# Inactive media session not restarted

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, android-mediasession

I've followed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#restarting-inactive-mediasessions) regarding restarting an inactive media session but it's not working for me. According to the documentation as long as you have the proper entry in the `AndroidManifest` it should just work.

In the logcat, I can see it's connecting to the `MediaBrowserService` but nothing happens:

```
2023-02-14 13:23:20.187 11970-11970 MediaBrowserCompat                       D  Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2023-02-14 13:23:20.216 11970-11970 ExoPlayerImpl                            I  Init 690e213 [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [redfin, Pixel 5, Google, 33]
2023-02-14 13:23:20.253 11970-11970 ExoPlayerImpl                            I  Release 690e213 [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [redfin, Pixel 5, Google, 33] [media3.common, media3.exoplayer, media3.decoder, media3.datasource, media3.extractor]
2023-02-14 13:23:20.760 11970-11970 MediaBrowserCompat                       D  Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2023-02-14 13:23:20.783 11970-11970 ExoPlayerImpl                            I  Init 7df60bd [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [redfin, Pixel 5, Google, 33]
2023-02-14 13:23:20.819 11970-11970 ExoPlayerImpl                            I  Release 7df60bd [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [redfin, Pixel 5, Google, 33] [media3.common, media3.exoplayer, media3.decoder, media3.datasource, media3.extractor]
2023-02-14 13:23:26.319 11970-11970 MediaBrowserCompat                       D  Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2023-02-14 13:23:26.345 11970-11970 ExoPlayerImpl                            I  Init 540e5f3 [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [redfin, Pixel 5, Google, 33]
2023-02-14 13:23:26.388 11970-11970 ExoPlayerImpl                            I  Release 540e5f3 [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [redfin, Pixel 5, Google, 33] [media3.common, media3.exoplayer, media3.decoder, media3.datasource, media3.extractor]
2023-02-14 13:23:27.001 11970-11970 MediaBrowserCompat                       D  Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2023-02-14 13:23:27.025 11970-11970 ExoPlayerImpl                            I  Init f1d97e0 [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [redfin, Pixel 5, Google, 33]
```

I'm know ExoPlayer has a `MediaSessionConnector` but the [documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html) doesn't say to use it and there's little code examples on how to implement it.

This is a stripped down version of my `MediaBrowserService` code:

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
    private ExoPlayer mPlayer;
    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSessionCompat;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mMediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(this, MediaPlayerService.class.getSimpleName());
        mMediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mMediaSessionCallback);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);

        mPlaybackBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
        mPlaybackBuilder.setActions(
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT);
                                
        setSessionToken(mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken());

        mPlaybackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();

        mPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build();
        mPlayer.addListener(new PlayerEventListener());
    }
    
    private final MediaSessionCompat.Callback mMediaSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            StopAudio();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();

            PlayAudio();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            PauseAudio();
        }
    };

    
     private class PlayerEventListener implements Player.Listener {

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
  
            } else if (state == Player.STATE_READY) {


            } else if (state == Player.STATE_ENDED)
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(null);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(false);
        mMediaSessionCompat.release();
        
        mPlayer.release();
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is this part in the documentation:

> If Android can identify the last active media session, it tries to
> restart the session by sending an ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON Intent to a
> manifest-registered component (such as a service or
> BroadcastReceiver).

This means you need to override `onMediaButtonEvent` in the `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` and restart playback there:

```
@Override
public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {

KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) mediaButtonEvent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

    if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY) {
    //restart playback
    }

    return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
}
```